# Accessing multiple values in .trig file blank node

Tags: sparql, jena, knowledge-graph

I've got a .trig file uploaded to Apache Jena Fuseki local server. The 3 named graphs inside the .trig file are centered around different flights - each graph has a snapshot of the traffic situation and flight data for a timestamp.

## DATA

The data is formatted as follows (I copied the relevant portion):

s1:ID_002
a plain:Flight;
plain:flightIdent s1:ID_004 .

s1:ID_004
a plain:FlightIdent ;
plain:aircraftIdent [ rdf:value "EXAMPLE" ] ;
plain:trajectory s1:ID_008 .

s1:ID_008
a plain:EfplTrajectoryRoutePair ;
plain:trajectory s1:ID_021 .

s1:ID_021
a plain:Trajectory ;
plain:trajectoryPoint s1:P1, s1:P2, s1:P3, s1:P4, s1:P5, s1:P6, s1:P7, s1:P8, s1:P9, s1:P10.

s1:P1
a plain:EfplTrajectoryPoint ;
plain:trajectoryPointType [ rdf:value 0 ] ;
plain:point s1:P11 .

s1:P11
a plain:EfplPoint4D ;
plain:pos [ rdf:value 46.123456789, 7.123456789] ;
plain:time [rdf:value "2021-01-01T00:00:01.000Z"^^xsd:dateTime] .

## PROBLEM

I am trying to query the graphs to get the aircraft position. Since the information I need is in a blank node, I have been using "rdf:value" as a predicate

```
SELECT ?aircraft ?position1 

FROM < graph >

WHERE { 
?aircraft plain:pos ?position
                  {?position rdf:value ?position1;

}
```

This returns data in this format
|aircraft |position1   |
|---------|------------|
|s1:P11   |46.123456789|
|s1:P11   |7.123456789 |
|s1:P21   |46.123456789|
|s1:P21   |7.123456789 |
|s1:P31   |46.123456789|
|s1:P31   |7.123456789 |

so each aircraft has its latitude, longitude values in a separate row. I tried making a separate variable for latitude and longitude, but then I have 4 entries per aircraft with permutations

latitude, latitude
latitude, longitude
longitude, latitude
longitude, longitude

I would like the (latitude, longitude) combination because that's the correct order, but I cannot isolate that specific output row.

A partially working query:

```
SELECT ?aircraft ?position_lat ?position_lon  

FROM < graph >

WHERE { ?aircraft plain:pos ?position; 
                  {?position rdf:value ?position_lat;
                             rdf:value ?position_lon}
  
FILTER (?position_lat != ?position_lon)

}
```

gives me the rows where the variables are different:

latitude, longitude
longitude, latitude

I cannot use ">" in the FILTER part because that may not be true in all use cases. What can I do to isolate the (longitude, latitude) row or get the data in a single variable (preferably separated by a comma)?
The values are going to be used in Java code later on, so I need to separate them into 2 variables or connect them to a single variable (to String parse).

Comment: the problem is in your data ... I mean, what is `plain:pos [ rdf:value 46.123456789, 7.123456789] ;` for a data construct? Why `rdf:value`? Why not using two predicates for lat and long? There are common vocabluaries for this, e.g. from WGS84. In it's current form there is no way to guarantee the correct order, this would only be possible if your data has a collection with a defined order, i.e. an **RDF list** or a **sequence**.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. 
I understand that the data is not formatted in the usual way, but the authors of the file were instructed to format it this way. All data is stored in blank nodes and can be accessed, with the exception of the position data because two values are stored in a single blank node.

Comment: maybe you misunderstand, but modeling it as `plain:pos [ rdf:value 46.123456789, 7.123456789] ;` is a misconception - you are simply loosing the information of the position when parsing it into RDF triples, it doesn't matter whether it's a blank node or not, in the end it results in a **set** of triples.

Comment: To be more specific: `[ rdf:value 46.123456789, 7.123456789] ;` is the same as `_:b0 rdf:value 46.123456789 .` and `_:b0 rdf:value 7.123456789 .` - so you simply have two RDF triples, nothing more, nothing less. There is no order on those triples. You simply can't solve this issue given that lat and long have an overlap in its range. Any RDF triple store will parse it into just a set of RDF triples, nothing in SPARQL helps you to distinguish lat from long (unless its > +-90 of course which always must be long) - long story short, the data has an issue only a human can solve

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @UninformedUser I understand the problem now. Changing the data solved the issue - I've elected to change it to a single, String-parseable variable by adding quotes around the values. Thank you for your answer!